# Messagebox in tkinter is unresponsive when I click the combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, messagebox

I have created a window with Combobox and Button. I wanted that a message box opens when I click the button. But the Messagebox is unresponsive when I click into the field in the combobox.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def fun1():
    messagebox.showinfo('','success')
def fun2():
    win2=Toplevel(win)
    win2.title('tianjiatx')
    Label(win2,text='label').grid(row=0,column=0)
    combobox1=ttk.Combobox(win2)
    combobox1['value']=('1','2','3')
    combobox1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    BT2=Button(win2,text='BT2')
    BT2['command']=fun1
    BT2.grid(row=1,column=0)
def main_win():
    global win
    win=Tk()
    win.geometry('400x600')
    BT1=Button(win,text='BT1')
    BT1['command']=fun2
    BT1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    win.mainloop()
main_win()
```

[image]

Comment: To begin with, do you find any difference between `BT1['command']=fun2` and `BT2['COMMAND']=fun2` ? Plus, you are never calling `fun1` which means the function never gets triggered and hence the `messagebox` is never shown

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry about the mistakes as you pointed out.I've corrected them.

Comment: The Messagebox is unresponsive after I selected value in Combobox.

Comment: the Messagebox is available if I input value by keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, not reproducible